# Center fullcalendar to current day

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

There is a possibility of centering the calendar for the current date? 
 My code looks like:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    height: 135
}) 

$('.fc-view-container').animate({
  scrollTop: $(".fc-today").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5rr6hkb1/) 
 However, the method presented above does not work, where I am doing wrong?
 Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
$('.fc-scroller').animate({
  scrollTop: $(".fc-today").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

You need to use the correct selector.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rr6hkb1/2/)